# Every $\mathbb{P}-$integrable function $u\in\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{P})$ is bounded (Counterexample)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(Ω,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. Find  a counterexample to the claim that every $\mathbb{P}-$integrable function $u\in\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{P})$  is bounded.

---

**Countableexample**

$(Ω,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P}) = (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\delta_n)$

$\delta_n$ is the Dirac measure in point $n\in\Bbb N$.

The function I have constructed is $u=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n \mathbb{1}_{A_n}$. $\mathbb{1}_{A_n}$ is the indicator function and $A_n=[-n,n]$. $u$ is unbounded, but have is it integrable?

Comment: But, unless I'm missing something, that's not even a probability space.

Comment: Why is  that ?@volJunkie

Comment: $n$ is not fixed?

Comment: $\delta_n(\mathbb{R}) = 1$ because @PeterFranek

Comment: Sure, but what is $u$? How much is $u(0)$? The $n$ in the sum is different from the fixed $n$ in $\delta_n$? Seems like confusing..

Comment: @PeterFranek You guys are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On $\mathbb N$, consider the probability measure $\mathbb P$ defined by
$$\mathbb P(\{n\}) = p_n \propto \frac 1{n^3}.$$

The identity function $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$ given by $f(n) = n$ is not bounded and
$$\int_{\mathbb N}|f|d\mathbb P \propto \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n^2} < \infty.$$

---

Another counterexample could be the expectation of a random variable following a Poisson distribution.